# Sending JSON object to the server via http GET

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for sending JSON object to the server via GET. 
Chris's answer on [Post an Array of Objects via JSON to ASP.Net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3) works for the  http POST but not for GET. 
My case also works for POST but not for GET. What can I do to make GET work
Here is my case:
in Controller I have the following method
       public ActionResult Screenreport(Screentable screendata)

```
   {
       // do something here
       return View();
   }
```

I have two ModelView as follows:

```
   public class Screenrecord
   {
      public string Firstname{ get; set; }
      public string Lastname{ get; set; }
   }
   public class Screentable
   {
      public List<Screenrecord> Screenlist { get; set; } 
   }
```

On the client side I generate JSON object

```
var Screentable = { Screenlist: screendata };
```

screendata  is an array of Screenrecord

All this work when I use POST but when I use GET I am getting null value (screendata = null) Controllers' method. 
In other word when click GO, screendata is null in Screenreport(Screentable screendata) routine.

Also, if I send one JSON object it works but if I send an array (list) like I described, it does not.
Is what I am trying to do doable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No :-)
Thats not how get works.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

(see 9.3 GET)

"The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI"

Request-URI being the important part here. There is no concept of body data in a **GET** request.

Comment: James, Thank you for your help. Would you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103260/return-pdf-to-browser-using-json-and-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Try changing method to public ActionResult Screenreport(HttpRequestMessage request)

Then use below code to get JSON object.

data = request.RequestUri.Query;
data = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data).Get("request");

Answer (score 0):

Try this example in Javascript:

```
var someObject = {
   id:123456,
   message:"my message",
}

var objStr = JSON.stringify(someObject);

var escapedObjStr = encodeURIComponent(objStr);

var getUrlStr = "http://myserver:port?json="+escapedObjStr
```

and now you can forward this URL to your server. I know this is not in any .NET language but you can definitely find the equivalent methods used, or just use the JS right away.