# Return PDF to browser using JSON and MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, pdf

I have a link as follows.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Report", "Screenreport", "Reports", null, new { @class = "subNavA AddBorderTop", id = "screenReport", title = "Create Report" })
```

Once the link is clicked, I have a the following jQuery code which creates a JSON object and post the information.

```
$().ready(function () {

   // Create Report fron the screen data
   $("#screenReport").live("click", function (event) { GenerateScreenReport(this, event); });

}) /* end document.ready() */

function GenerateScreenReport(clikedtag, event) {

   var table = $(".EvrakTable").html();
   var screendata = tableParser(table);
   var Screentable = { Screenlist: screendata };

   var myurl = $(clikedtag).attr("href");
   var title = $(clikedtag).attr("title");


   $.ajax({ 
      url: myurl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(Screentable),
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function () { alert("Got it"); }
   }); 

};
```

To Handle JSON I have the following two classes. Realize two classes in the same namespace

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
   public class Screenrecord
   {
      public string Fname{ get; set; }
      public string LName { get; set; }
      public string Age { get; set; }
      public string DOB { get; set; }
   }


   public class Screentable
   {
      public List<Screenrecord> Screenlist { get; set; } 
   }
}
```

ANd in my controller, I have the following code:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public FileStreamResult Screenreport(Screentable screendata)
   {
      MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
      MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
      Document document = new Document();
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
      document.Open();
      document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
      document.Add(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
      document.Close();

      byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
      outputStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
      outputStream.Position = 0;

      return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf");

   }
```

This code is supposed to gerate PDF. 
if I leave [HttpPost] as it is, it does NOT generate PDF and it goes to /Screenreport page, however I see my JSON is passed to the controller properly. 
(screendata is populated properly - in controller)

But if I comment out [HttpPost], it DOES generate a PDF but screendata (in controller) is null.

Can someone please explain whats's going on and help me figure it out. Thanksin advance.

Comment: Isn't there a brave soul to help me out? I am stuck here. It looks like a technology issue not an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel obligated to post my answer since I didn't hear from anyone. I ended up creating a form that includes a hidden input, then saved my json object in the hidden input and then submit the form. This time I will get input as an string not a json or xml.

```
var $hidInput = $("#dataToReport"); 
$hidInput.val(JSON.stringify(Screentable)); 
$('#frmScreenreport').submit();
```

Thanks all anyways.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use AJAX to download files, because javascript doesn't allow you to save the downloaded content.
To workaround this you need to take **2 steps**.

**First:** make the HTTP Post request, and in the controller action we would store the File content in a Memory stream.**Second:** on success make another call by setting the window.location to the Download Action method

In your Controller create this 2 actions:

```
public ActionResult GenerateFile()
    {
        MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream { Position = 0 };
        //position = 0 is important

        var fName = string.Format("File-{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
        Session[fName] = fileStream;
        return Json(new { success = true, fName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fName)
    {
        var ms = Session[fName] as MemoryStream;
        if (ms == null)
            return new EmptyResult();
        Session[fName] = null;
        return File(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fName);
    }
```

In your javascript:

```
$('#Donwload-button').click(function () {
    data = JSON.stringify(YOURDATA);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/YOURCONTROLLER/GenerateFile",
        data: data,
        success: function (d) {
            if (d.success) {
                window.location = "/YOURCONTROLLER/DownloadFile" + "?fName=" + d.fName;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
           alert("Error");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Very nice solution! I use it for background report creation that took some time.

Comment: I would try not to use sessions to store the pdf contents in... If your PDF download is large then this will use up the server memory.

Comment: Finally! This has bogged me down for over a year, with me coding some pretty ridiculous hacks to download PDFs from AJAX calls. Thank you for this valid workaround.