# Getting ReadTimeOut Exception while returning PDF from controller to view

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, itext

I want to download pdf when the user clicks on print button.

My controller method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult CreatePDF()
        {
            MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream).CloseStream = false;

            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            document.Close();

            byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
            workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            workStream.Position = 0;

            return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
        }
```

And here's how I am calling it from view:

```
 $('#print').click(function (evt) {
                window.location.href = "/api/pdfdownload/createpdf";
            });
```

I am getting the following error upon clicking the print button:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the
>   response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
>   
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>     An error has
>   occurred.  Error getting value from
>   'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'. 
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
>    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()
>     An error has
>   occurred. Timeouts are not supported on
>   this stream.
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout() at
>   GetReadTimeout(Object ) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)

I just dont understand what this exception means in this context. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It means it couldn't serialize your object of type `MemoryStream` into JSON:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type **failed to serialize the response body** for
>   **content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'**.
>   System.InvalidOperationException An error has occurred. Error getting
>   value from 'ReadTimeout' on **'System.IO.MemoryStream'.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException...**

My guess is that you are trying, maybe by intent and maybe not, to serialize MemoryStream into JSON, which is not out of the blue as you are dealing with PDF files, while you cannot do this. 
MemoryStream contains bytes and cannot be serialized as JSON.

I would suggest you to look at this [post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2057281.aspx?The%20ObjectContent%201%20type%20failed%20to%20serialize%20the%20response%20body%20for%20content%20type%20application%20json%20charset%20utf%208%20) from asp.net forums but without anymore information, that is all there is to produce.

Comment: How do I fix this issue? I am not intending to return JSON. All I want to do is downoad pdf file but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: You will have to share more code, where you download the pdf. This is not enough to diagnose the situation.

Comment: This is the answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103260/return-pdf-to-browser-using-json-and-mvc