# Send values by GET method

Tags: android

I have been trying to send data to server through GET method but I am unable to find a way to do it. I have tried few codes in asynchronous task but nothing. The web services are made in cakePhp and the format is like this:

```
Base_URI/users/add.json?json={“email”: xxx@x.com, “password”: “xxxxxxxxx”, “first_name”: “Xyz”, “last_name”: “Xyz”}
```

Android experts are requested to figure a way out of this problem. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", UserDummy.email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", UserDummy.password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", UserDummy.fname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name", UserDummy.lname));
            // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            url += "?json={" + paramString+"}";                                                                                                                                                     ;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("XXX", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("XXX", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("XXX", e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
```

HttpGet is not accepting this format of url and is giving the error but when I try it on browser it works fine. Error is following:

```
Illegal character in query at index 56
```

Comment: post your code,...we'll help fix it

Comment: Are you sure you should be using a JSON as a GET parameter; what's wrong with normal name-value pairs. Also, you'd need to encode that JSON to base64 and lastly, i believe there's a 255 character limit on GET request but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Also, I dunno if you've developed the server implementation, but it's best not to send email and password over a GET request. Encrypting both parameters and POSTing them is a more secure approach.

Comment: The request being executed here is a `POST` request not a `GET` request. Are you sure this is what you want ?

Comment: @Halim No, I know I would have to use namevaluepairs, but don't know how

Comment: @Shahzeb Why don't you use a `HttpGet` request instead, and use a name value pair (from your example `json`/your_actual_json_serialized_object) ?

Comment: that is what I am asking. I mean how ?

Comment: Just switch your `HttpPost` to a `HttpGet`. Then you'd need to build a `BasicNameValuePair` just as you did in your example, having a key corresponding to "json" and a value corresponding to the string serialized representation of your `UserDummy` object (an example of how to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571092/convert-object-to-json-in-android).

Comment: Actually I am stuck on '=' sign. Its giving me error because of this part "?json={}"

Comment: @Halim please have a look on my code and tell me what to do. Thanks

Comment: This is the error in the logcat:
01-19 05:06:25.531: V/XXX(1182): Illegal character in query at index 56

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45570/discussion-between-shahzeb-and-halim-qarroum)

Comment: BTW, you can get the respone string from Entity by using: `String response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after debugging and trying different solutions the whole day, I solved the problem :)

I needed to encode the parameters part and not the whole URL like this:

```
String url = "Base_URI/users/add.json?json=";
    url =url +  URLEncoder.encode("{\"email\":\""+email+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\"}", "UTF-8");
```

Thanks everyone for your support !

Answer (score 0):

Use volley lib for networking in android.

Comment: There is no need to use any third party library here. Android comes with the `org.apache.http` package built-in which already has everything needed in order to do what the OP wants.

Comment: Volley is more up to date networking in android. And it very simple

Comment: Maybe, but it adds unnecessary heavyness in your app as you could use the built-in method, which is not really complicated to use compared to what the OP wants.

Comment: tried volley library too but this is too not getting url format.

Answer (score 0):

Your string comparisons are not right.

This compares object references and will not work for you:

```
method == "POST"
```

Intead, use equals():

```
"POST".equals(method);
```

You can also do:

```
method.equals("POST");
```

but that may cause an error if method is null.

Comment: This isn't the issue. Its working perfectly fine. The issue here is parsing json from given url by GET method

Comment: According to the code you posted, "is" will be null. It will never be set. No HTTP method will be chosen. The error logs in your other message confirm that. If there is a problem parsing, it is because you are parsing null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use method GET:

This method may help you

```
/**
 * 
 * @param url stands for API
 * @param 
 *      params[i][0] stands for column's name
 *      params[i][1] stands for value which respective with column's name
 * @return InputStream which got from Server
 */
public static int sendJSONObject(IGetUserData iUserId, String method, String url, String[]... params) {
    InputStream mInputStream = null;
    HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
    HttpRequestWithEntity mHttpGet = null;
    int status = Def.REQUEST_INVALID;
    try {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        mHttpGet = new HttpRequestWithEntity(url, method);

        JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject();
        for (String[] pair : params) {
            mObject.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }

        StringEntity mStringEntity = new StringEntity(mObject.toString());
        mStringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        mStringEntity.setContentType("application/json");

        mHttpGet.setEntity(mStringEntity);          
        HttpResponse mResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
        status = mResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.d(TAG, "status: " + status);
        if (mResponse != null && 
                (status == Def.CREATED || status == Def.OK)) {
            mInputStream = mResponse.getEntity().getContent();  
            if(mInputStream != null){
                String json = StreamUtils.converStreamToString(mInputStream);
                userId = JSONUtils.getUserId(json);
                iUserId.sendUserId(userId);
                Log.d("viet","userid = " + userId);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during send");
        status = Def.NETWORK_ERROR;
    }
    return status;
}
```

---

Right here is what you need.

```
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    mHttpGet = new HttpRequestWithEntity(url, method);

    JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject();
    for (String[] pair : params) {
        mObject.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

    StringEntity mStringEntity = new StringEntity(mObject.toString());
    mStringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
    mStringEntity.setContentType("application/json");

    mHttpGet.setEntity(mStringEntity);          
    HttpResponse mResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
```

And here is **HttpRequestWithEntity.java**

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;

public class HttpRequestWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    private String method;

    public HttpRequestWithEntity(String url, String method) {
        if (method == null || (method != null && method.isEmpty())) {
            this.method = HttpMethod.GET;
        } else {
            this.method = method;
        }
        try {
            setURI(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return this.method;
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't think so that can possible send `Json` via `HttpGet` method,

Comment: It works for me, and I used it in my project. :) Did you try?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073896/sending-json-object-to-the-server-via-http-get

Comment: ;) We can fake something. :D If it doesn't work, I can not share. hehe