# how to add a json to a getHttp java request?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to get some data from the server according to my auth-token.

According to the REST principals i need ti use GET method.

but i don't want to send the user auth-token in the request url.

How can i add a json to the httpGet instance?

```
        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpGet.setEntity(se);
```

`httpGet.setEntity` throws an error

`The method setEntity(StringEntity) is undefined for the type HttpGet`

Comment: The method setEntity(StringEntity) is undefined for the type HttpGet

Comment: you can send `json` with `httpPost`, you can't post json with `httpGet`

Comment: Oh, right. Get method has not any body. you should do all on your url! like "http://stackoverflow.com/name=Hossein&value=Mobasher" so, your json should convert to url encoded string.

Comment: then in my case using rest you would suggest using POST +json **or** GET with quesryString ? after all i want to get data from the server

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073896/sending-json-object-to-the-server-via-http-get

Comment: @HosseinMobasher but i recall from my times in web developing sending body with get is possible. for cases just like this

Comment: Based on "http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/860721" : **"You can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning. If you give it meaning by parsing it on the server and changing your response based on its contents you're violating the HTTP/1.1 spec."**

Comment: You can also take a look at "http://stackoverflow.com/a/12535806/860721"

Comment: thanks, then why would i send `body if it has not have any meaning`?
so in that case when i need t **GET** data from the server but don't want to expose my authToken i should use **POST** ?

Comment: If you want to get anything from server, you should use `GET` method (with note that ReST!). You can add your json to url with url encoder methods.