# CURL: can it have the data in the HTTP GET?

Tags: http, curl

the following code snippet doesn't make sense to me.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_phrase": { "address": "mill lane" } }
}
'
```

Does HTTP GET contain a body (data)?

Answer (score 0):

No, `GET` takes only a [`QUERY_STRING`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), but no data.

Usually data are sent via `POST` or `PUT` HTTP verbs

Check http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: In my example, it does take data. The query is not a querystring. This is an official example of the ElasticSearch.

Comment: Having a reference link please ?

Comment: Here you go! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_executing_searches.html

Comment: Very confusing me, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073896/sending-json-object-to-the-server-via-http-get

Comment: "Sending JSON object to the server via http GET" this is confusing me. My question is how this scenario can exist, however, it does exist. By the way, I didn't get the answer from that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here! In the ElasticSearch Docs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html

The HTTP libraries of certain languages (notably JavaScript) don’t allow GET requests to have a request body. In fact, some users are surprised that GET requests are ever allowed to have a body.

...