# Send array to MVC controller via JSON?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying, and struggling, to send an array via JSON to a MVC controller action.

Here is what I have and what i've tried...

```
//Get checked records
var $checkedRecords = $(':checked'); //e.g. 3 rows selected = [input 4, input 5, input 6]

//Have tried following:
sendingVar: $checkedRecords.serializeArray(); // gives array of 0's
sendingVar: JSON.stringify($checkedRecords); // gives "{\"length\":1,\"prevObject\":{\"0\":{\"jQuery1313717591466\":1,\"jQuery1313717591653\":13},\"context\":{\"jQuery1313717591466\":1,\"jQuery1313717591653\":13},\"length\":1},\"context\":{\"jQuery1313717591466\":1,\"jQuery1313717591653\":13},\"selector\":\":checked\",\"0\":{}}"...wtf

//Post
$.post(url, { sendingVar: sendingVar }, function(data) {alert(data); });
```

How do I do it ?

edit: to those that suggest sending `$checkedRecords` "as is" from the top line - that is not working. I get a strange exception somewhere in the jquery framework :(

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://.../.../.../jquery-1.4.4.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 141" data: no]
```

which I think means it is attempting to assign null to something it cannot.

Edit: i'm using MVC2 not 3

Edit2: After @Monday's answer- **the problem is due to how I have built the array like** `[input 4, input 5, input 6]` and not `[4,5,6]` - any ideas how I can just get the values in the array instead ?

Edit3: Stop voting up duplicate when it's not. Did you actually read my problem or read the problems linked? this is a different issue

@Daveo:

[I don't want to build in an overriding custom attribute just to send an array from JSON, that is rediculous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll) as we've already covered in this question-it is not necessary.

[MVC3 - irrelevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3)

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: What is your desired result? Your array is of jQuery objects, the stringify version looks right to me. What are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: it is just an array containing string ID's of the checked items. I want checkedRecords to contain an array of all ID's of items selected. The selected input's `value` contains the ID value I need.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is my demo,use mvc2,hope some helps~

The key to success is [traditional](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

set the `traditional` parameter to true

```
$(function(){
    var a = [1, 2];
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Home/PostArray/") %>",
       data: {orderedIds: a},
       dataType: "json",
       traditional: true,
       success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
    });
})
```

Since jquery 1.4 this parameter exists because the mechanism to serialize objects into query parameters has changed.

and action is~

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostArray(int[] orderedIds)
{
    return Content(orderedIds.Length.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `orderedIds` is null in the controller method. I suspect because ajax actually does a `GET`?

Comment: @baron - In my location, it works fine. `orderedIds` is a parameter name

Comment: Hmmm apologies, you are correct this code does work. So the problem lies in how I am getting the array of checked Id's with `var $checkedRecords = $(':checked');` which gives me `[input 3, input 4, input 5]` where I actually need: `[1, 2]`. Thank you

Comment: thanks, i got it with `var items = [];
            $("input:checked").each(function () { items.push($(this).val()); });`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `JSON.stringyfy` to sent the data as a string then use `JavaScriptSerializer class` to retrive the data.

In C# code, to get the data, will look like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

js.Deserialize<T>(string paramiter);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code

```
var url = '/sampleController/sampleAction'
var params = {sendingVar: [1,2]}
$.post(url, params , function (data) {
   $("#lblResult").html(' : ' + data);
}).fail(function (e) {
   alert(e);
});
```