# Pass an array of strings from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send array to MVC controller via JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116099/send-array-to-mvc-controller-via-json)

I haven't really found a good solution to this so far.

My javascript/jQuery and I try to send the data using ajax.

```
    var val = new Array();
    $( ':checkbox:checked' ).each( function ( i )
    {
        console.log( $( this ).val() );
        val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    removeSelected(val);


function removeSelected(listOfStuff)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("removeSelected"))',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { listOfStuff: listOfStuff },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( return_data )
        {
            $( ":checkbox:checked" ).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
```

And my controller. The array comes in as null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool removeSelected ( string[] listOfStuff )
    {
       //do stuff
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick shot in the dark: Have you tried doing `'listOfStuff': listOfStuff` (with '' on the key)?

Comment: Probably your array on the client side doesn't really have strings inside but numbers or whatever but not strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `traditional: true` suggestion referenced [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116267/74757), which, from [the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), is:

> A Boolean indicating whether to perform a traditional "shallow" serialization.

That change would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@(Url.Action("removeSelected"))',
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { listOfStuff: listOfStuff },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( return_data )
    {
        $( ":checkbox:checked" ).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

In addition, may I make a small suggestion for your code? I would change this:

```
var val = new Array();
$( ':checkbox:checked' ).each( function ( i )
{
    console.log( $( this ).val() );
    val[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

to:

```
var val = []; // use this array notation
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function ()
{
    console.log($(this).val());
    val.push($(this).val()); // use push() instead of an index
});
```