# How to send JSON Array to an ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send JSON array to ASP MVC Controller.  I first tried a JSON object and it did work but failed while I tried the array JSON object.  As the coding showed below, I expected to get the 
ListForm2 to be,

ListForm2[0].MarketID = 1, ......

ListForm2[1].MarketID = 2, ......

However, I got the ListForm2=null.  What's wrong in my coding?

```
function ProcessSaveView(area, bChecked, bChart, saveName) {
    var jsondata = [{ MarketID: 1, ForecastPointTypeID: 5, ForecastPointID: 21, CustomTimeZoneID: "ET-Prevailing", IsChart: true },
                    { MarketID: 2, ForecastPointTypeID: 5, ForecastPointID: 51, CustomTimeZoneID: "ET-Prevailing", IsChart: true }];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./charts/SaveViewToDatabase",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: jsondata,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("Save View successful!");
            } else {
                alert("Duplicate View already exist. Not save!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("No market, load type & region is selected!");
        }
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveViewToDatabase(testJsonObject[] ListForm2)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}

public class testJsonObject
{
    public int ForecastPointID { get; set; }
    public int MarketID { get; set; }
    public int ForecastPointTypeID { get; set; }
    public string CustomTimeZoneID { get; set; }
    public bool IsChart { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Array as JSON to MVC Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007722/post-array-as-json-to-mvc-controller)

Comment: verify your json structure its maybe the mistake

Comment: change the name jsondata for ListForm2={all values} show this forum   .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116099/send-array-to-mvc-controller-via-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./charts/SaveViewToDatabase",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            alert("Save View successful!");
        } else {
            alert("Duplicate View already exist. Not save!");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("No market, load type & region is selected!");
    }
});
```

See added `contentType` and `JSON.stringify` into `data` attribute.