# My json object becomes null when it reaches my controller function

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know this question has been asked many times, but this is different.

I have kendo grdi which i get selected and not selected type, the user have free role to make changes and that works. I did tried exmples like this [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax) ,[Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116099/send-array-to-mvc-controller-via-json) and many others.

Now the problem is my json object that am trying to pass to the controller became null, I this is what i have tried below.

Can you please correct me if there's something wrong am doing ?

Javascript

JsonObj : This is what i get when i deselect from grid checkbox

```
[ { mailID: '10' , roleID: '5' , isMailSelected: 'false' } , { 
  mailID: '11' , roleID: '5' , isMailSelected: 'false' } , { 
 mailID: '19' , roleID: '9' , isMailSelected: 'false' } ]





function goToControllerSave() {
    var jsonObj = displayFilterResults();
    $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Account")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: { myobj: jsonObj },  
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    })

}


$(function () {
    $('#Grid1').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#Grid1').data().kendoGrid;
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        dataItem.set('isSelected', checked);
    })
})


//My json obj: this returns results on Alert

function displayFilterResults() {
    var items = "[";
    var dataSource = $("#Grid1").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;   
    var filters = dataSource.filter();
    var allData = dataSource.data();
    var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
    var filteredData = query.filter(filters).data;

  items = items + " { mailID: '" + item.mailID + "' , roleID: '" + 
  item.roleID + "' , isSelected: '" + item.isSelected + "' } ,";

    }); 
    if (items.charAt(items.length - 1) == ',') {
        items = items.substr(0, items.length - 1);
    }
    items = items + "]";

    alert(items)
    return items;
}
```

My conntroller

```
   public class myItems
    {

        public string mailID { set; get; }
        public string roleID { set; get; }
        public string isSelected { set; get; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(List<myItems> myobj)
    {
       --------------
       --------------
    }
```

Comment: You controler method expects an array. Maybe it helps when you change `data: { myobj: jsonObj }` to `data: jsonObj,`.

Comment: @NtFreX I have already tried that and it still pass null

Comment: What you are passing to the controller from JavaScript is string. You should create object array first and then use JSON.stringify to convert json string to be sent to controller.

Comment: Can you please show me how ?

Comment: I think you just need to replace `data: { myobj: jsonObj },` by `data: displayFilterResults(),`. as **displayFilterResults** returns a stringified json object

Comment: I have tried that and it just returns null

Comment: Is this aspnet mvc?

Comment: @Julian, Yes. this is mvc application

Comment: Also, please capture the posted json. Makes it all more clear. Just use debugging tools

Comment: please add the json you're generating to that question

Comment: let me generate json and send it

Comment: Why not just get the data in a 'non-modified' state i.e. just `filteredData` and use `JSON.stringify` when sending to the controller? e.g. `data: { myobj: JSON.stringify(jsonObj) },`?

Comment: @Sandman it still return null

Comment: Can you help me change my jsonobj format to this formart below; my format its wrong,it whout be like this

{
  "items": [
    {
      "maiID": 1,
      "roleID": 1,
      "isMailSelected": true
    },
    {
      "mailID": 1,
      "roleID": 1,
      "isMailSelected": true
    }
  ]
}

Comment: the problem is, format of json is not correct

Comment: @derloopkat correct, the format should be like this below and am not sure how i can get this right..can you help with this fomart ?

 { "items": [ { "maiID": 1, "roleID": 1, "isMailSelected": true }, { "mailID": 1, "roleID": 1, "isMailSelected": true } ] }

Comment: `JSON.stringify( { myobj: jsonObject})` should work

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you mention, json object is an actual object, not the string representation. Then `JSON.stringify()` is used to get string formatted using double quotation marks, removing spare spaces, etc. Unfortunately MVC application has trouble parsing json that doesn't look like this.

Since you create a string directly, you need to produce similar json format.

```
var json = '{"myobj":[';
json +='{mailID:"10",roleID:"5",isMailSelected:"false"},';
json+='{mailID:"11",roleID:"5",isMailSelected:"false"},';
json +='{mailID:"19",roleID:"9",isMailSelected:"false"}'
json +=']}';
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Account")',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: json,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
})
```

In the class I have updated the name of member **isSelected**, cause I saw it didn't match json and I assume you changed it to isMailSelected.

```
public class myItems
{
    public string mailID { set; get; }
    public string roleID { set; get; }
    public string isMailSelected { set; get; }
}
```

In my controller I have the same you posted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<myItems> myobj)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: this looks like will work after getting the correct format, it must be like the one. which means names are in qouts. how can i get that ?

{
  "items": [
    {
      "mailID ": + item.mailID +,
      "roleID": + item.roleID +,
      "isMailSelected ": item.isSelected 
    },
    {
     "mailID": + item.mailID +,
      "roleID": + item.roleID +,
      "isMailSelected ": item.isSelected 
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I believe code would be better if you simply create a json object and push items into the array rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to say

Comment: In my code it also works if I do var json = { myobj: [] };
    json.myobj.push({ mailID: 'billgates@micrsoft.com', roleID: 'President' }); Then in Ajax call: data: JSON.stringify(json) You can populate the array by pushing items into json.myobj. Then stringify will format.

Comment: Then just amend displayFilterResults() for producing formatted json

Comment: var jsonObj = displayFilterResults(); and then on ajax i did this and still returns null

data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),

Comment: because this function is not iterating to generate items, it only try to create one and even this part is probably wrong. The variable item should be set while iterating through items.

Comment: Now am running out of options on what to do as am not getting results

Comment: you have a kendo datasource then iterate through items, see https://telerikhelper.net/2013/02/26/how-to-iterate-all-the-data-in-kendo-ui-data-source/ there is a *for* statement by the end of the page. For each item in the datasource you add an item in you json array.

Comment: If that code isn't clear then create new question in stackoverflow.

Comment: I have formatted my json to the required format and it looks good as i have validated it online. Now the problem is when passing it to the action, count is 0...not sure what am i missing