# Trouble sending JSON data to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3 I am not having any luck trying to send JSON data to my controller.

I loop through a list and generate JSON objects from the elements and then send them off along with my query parameter:

```
$.each(addedIngredients.find('li'), function () {
    ingredients[count] = {
        ID: $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1],
        Name: $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0]
    };
    count++;
});

request = $.ajax({
    url: '/Ingredients/SearchIngredients',
    data: {
        q: q,
        ingredients: ingredients
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
             //Code omitted
    },
    error: function () {
             //Code omitted
    }
});
```

At the controller I have

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult SearchIngredients(string q, JSONIngredient[] ingredients)
    {
        //Initialise model
        List<JSONIngredient> model = new List<JSONIngredient>();

        //Add items to list
        ir.GetIngredients(q).ToList().ForEach(i => model.Add(new JSONIngredient(i)));

        //Return model as JSON object
        return this.Json(model);
    }
```

Where JSONingredient is

```
public class JSONIngredient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public JSONIngredient()
    {
    }

    public JSONIngredient(Ingredient Ingredient)
    {
        this.ID = Ingredient.ID;
        this.Name = Ingredient.Name;
    }
}
```

Which I made up because I thought my normal model which has additional properties which are not in the JSON was causing the problem, but I would have thought that if it did work it would have worked with my normal model...

I'm thinking that maybe the format in which I am sending the data is not correct. Examining the request in firefox show:

Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
ingredients[0][ID]  4
ingredients[0][Name]    Water
q                   sug

Source

q=sug&ingredients%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Water&ingredients%5B0%5D%5BID%5D=4

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you receive in your controller?

Comment: I always get the correct value for "q" and null for "ingredients".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call JSON.stringify around your data.
See here for an example:
[Post an Array of Objects via JSON to ASP.Net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3)

Try first with just 'q', then try as just 'ingredients'

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with this for a while and trying this and that I finally got it to work. As I suspected the data format was incorrect. Instead of sending a pure JSON object

```
data: {
    q: q,
    ingredients: ingredients
}
```

I needed to send a stringified object:

```
JSON.stringify({ q: q, ingredients: ingredients})
```

Simple when you know it.

Comment: Yup, just saw that, sorry. But since you took the time to reply I'll award you the answer.