# How to get the post json data in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

Can u help me to how to get the json data in controller.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: 'getdata',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(value), //value is an array
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {                    
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult getdata()
{
   view()
}
```

I dont have any idea about the controller or model .Suggest some ideas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317856/asp-net-mvc-posting-json/15318612#15318612

Answer (score 0):

Jenu,

You'll need to have a parameter of the type that matches your json model along the lines of:

your model may look like:

```
public class MyModel{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName{get; set;)
    public bool IsHappy {get; set;}
    // etc. etc
}

public ActionResult GetData(MyModel data)
{
   // do what you need with the data here
   return View();
}
```

This question is so braod that I think you'd be best to google up some searches for 'json model asp.net mvc' and take it from there. I'll add a few links later.

**[edit]** - as promised, a few links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124541/Working-on-JSON-objects-in-jQuery-and-MVC
- http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx
- [Asp.Net mvc, posting json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317856/asp-net-mvc-posting-json)

THe final link in the list above almost gives a perfect blow by blow account of what you need to do. I suggest you study that well. good luck.

Comment: I already google up and didnt get clear understanding . can u help me to declare in model

Comment: see edit... tho it will depend on what your model properties are. rough attempt to show generis type teaser