# How do I read the Json object from a rest call?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

This is my first exposure to working with the HttpClient.

I can see the status codes that come back from the rest call, but I'm unsure how can I read the json object that is returned from the GetData method?

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);

            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("API/GetData");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task MyTest() {
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("API/GetData");

        if(response!=null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

the `json` variable will hold the string representation of the JSON. from there you can use it as needed.

also take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm so that you can use strongly typed instances of the json

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317856/asp-net-mvc-posting-json/15318612#15318612 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: Thank you.  That worked, but opened up a new challenge on working with async methods.

Comment: There is a lot of information in SO about that topic.