# How to get the values from view to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamic table in this table have a multiple columns like name age marks1 marks2 marks3 and one button delete when click on delete button row will deleted in database

i wrote for button click in jquery like this

```
$(document).delegate(".delete"+this.name, "click", function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Deletesutdentrecord","StudentDetails")',
        success: function () {
            var valid = true
    if (confirm('are you sure to delete this?.'))
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    valid = false;
}
    });
});
```

and my controller code is

```
 public JsonResult Deletesutdentrecord()
    {
        try
        {
            StudentViewModel studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
            parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", studentViewModel.Name);
            result = DataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_Deletestudent", parameters);               
            return Json(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error");
        }
    }
```

and my view is

```
  $.each(data.list, function (index, item) {
            var row = $('<tr class="data"></tr>');
            row.append($('<td class="name"></td>').text(item.Name));
            row.append($('<td class="age"></td>').text(item.Age));
            row.append($('<td ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks1 + ' size="10px" class="marks" id=marks1_' + index + ' name=' + index + ' maxlength="3"/></td>'));
            row.append($('<td ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks2 + ' size="10px" class="marks" id=marks2_' + index + ' name=' + index + ' maxlength="3"/></td>'));
            row.append($('<td ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks3 + ' size="10px" class="marks" id=marks3_' + index + ' name=' + index + ' maxlength="3"/></td>'));               
            row.append($('<td><input type="Button" value="Edit" class=edit_'+index+'</td>'));
            row.append($('<td id=delete_'+index+'><input type="Button" value="Delete" class="delete" </td>'));
     });
```

but here in my controller it showing null values how to get the values on delete row values

Comment: you are not sending any data to controller

Comment: You need to pass the ID of the object you want to delete to the method.

Comment: In your AJAX server call, you need to pass the `Name`, which you are not passing.

Comment: how to pass the data to contoller

Comment: use onclick  function with id of the row.On function definition redirect to controllers url.

Comment: Check this reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599280/send-javascript-array-in-ajax-beginform

Comment: additionally please note that in your js method you are deleting student first then you are asking if user is sure:D