# AJAX Posting Slickgrid data to MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid and am attempting to save its data back to the server.

When I breakpoint on the server, I can see the data in the Request.Form object, but I can't make it work with my object.

My data looks like...

```
[
{"id":"0","LineNumber":"","Detail":"MOT cost","Code":" ","Qty":"1","Est":"  ","CustomerDamage":false,"Cost":"44.00","Value":"44.00","VAT":true,"SelfBillingLine":"False","DefectStatus":"    "},
{"id":"62","LineNumber":"","Detail":"CRACKS IN Chassis","Code":"TLMA02","Qty":"1","Est":"","CustomerDamage":false,"Cost":"35.00","Value":"35.00","VAT":true,"SelfBillingLine":"False","DefectStatus":"Large repair"},
{"id":"63","LineNumber":"","Detail":"TEAR IN N/S CURTAIN","Code":"TLMA02","Qty":"1","Est":"","CustomerDamage":true,"Cost":"10.00","Value":"10.00","VAT":true,"SelfBillingLine":"False","DefectStatus":"Customer"}
]
```

I am posting with a button onclick...

```
 $("#SBSave").click(function() {
          debugger;
          var details = JSON.stringify(defectrows);
          save('SBDetail/SaveSBItem', details);
      });
```

I have tried a number of things to receive the data, none of them work.

My controller...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveSBItem(SelfBillDetailList details, string Approve = "")
    {
         // Actions here.
    }
```

My model...
Trying a number of things, neither work...

```
public class SelfBillDetailList
{
    public IEnumerable<SelfBillingIncomingDetail> IncomingDetails { get; set; }
}


public class SelfBillingIncomingDetail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Est { get; set; }
    public bool VAT { get; set; }
    public bool CustomerDamage { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Received { get; set; }
    public string DefectStatus { get; set; }
    public bool SelfBillingLine { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have tried an individual SelfBillingIncomingDetail and also a the SelfBillDetailList.

Neither work.

I have even sent an individual row, again, neither work.

I want to send it as a group, so it will be an array of SelfBillingIncomingDetail but nothing works.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it again... eventually found an answer after looking for ages.

Darin Dimitrov's answer in
[Post an Array of Objects via JSON to ASP.Net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3)
let me to the answer.

It seems that when sending the data, I need to give the array of data the same name as the property name in SelfBillDetailList, so...

```
var details = JSON.stringify({IncomingDetails : defectrows});
```

fixes it.